# JQuery second child

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child

I have the following code.

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="first leaf"></li>
<li class="leaf"></li>

<li class="expanded">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="first leaf"></li>
        <li class="leaf"></li>
        <li class="leaf"></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class="leaf"></li>
<li class="leaf"></li>

<li class="expanded">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="first leaf"></li>
        <li class="leaf"></li>
        <li class="leaf"></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class="leaf"></li>
<li class="leaf"></li>
</ul>
```

And the following js:

```
if (($("body").hasClass("page-node-4"))) {
    $( ".expanded > ul" ).first().show();
}

if (($("body").hasClass("page-node-13"))) {
    $( ".expanded > ul:nth-child(2)").show();
}
```

My problem is that the second `if` statement doesn't work. The first works. I think i have a mistake in the `ul:nth-child(2)` part. But i can't find the correct method. Could you help me?

Comment: Does the body have the class `page-node-13`?

Comment: The body class is changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean to get the second occurrence of it in the document. Here, you're getting the second child of its parent, and there is none.

```
if (($("body").hasClass("page-node-13"))) {
    $( ".expanded > ul").eq(1).show();
}
```

jQuery's `.eq()` method takes a 0-based index of the element in the set to return.